# SAS code runs with 0 observations if called from %INCLUDE

Tags: sas, include

I'd like to start by saying I'm no SAS wiz by no means.
I inherited SAS code from a team that no longer exists which was written by people who no longer work here, so there is nobody around that would be more familiar with how things work.

The structure of things is:
We have a SAS program that works as a scheduler for triggering a selection of smaller programs in a daily basis. The way it works is using statements to check for the time of day and based on that it then triggers programs that are stored in the server by using an %include statement.

This has worked flawlessly for the past 2 years and suddenly from yesterday on all the codes that are triggered by this scheduler are running with 0 observations.

If I manually open a program in the server (the same program that the scheduler triggers) it runs fine. If the scheduler triggers it then the log shows me that the data set has 0 observations and then stops the step.
This happens for every step in a program since the first one, which can be as simple as the step outlined below:

```
data drawdown;
set server01.legacy_mapping_drawdown;
run;
```

If I run the above step manually, log shows:

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.drawdown has 13643 observations and 107 variables.
```

If this is triggered by the %include statement, then the log reads:

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.drawdown has 0 observations and 107 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.drawdown was not replaced because this step was stopped.
```

I have no clue whatsoever as to why this would be happening.
The fact that this started happening on the 02/02/2020 leads me to believe that the new year might have something to do with it.
The code in the scheduler hasn't been touched at all in a while and the several codes are being triggered. It's how they perform that changes depending on being triggered manually or via the scheduler.

I know there is little to no technical details here but there isn't much to it really.

Would appreciate any ideas on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the macro?

Comment: Add the `/source2` option to the `%include` statement so that the log will show the lines of code read from that file.  Also include the lines from the SAS log from the step generated by the `%include` statement.  Either the file is different than you expected or perhaps the lines are being truncated. You might need to check the system options for LRECL and/or S2 and perhaps add those options to your %INCLUDE statement.

Comment: There should be some type of error message before the messages quoted to explain why the step was stopped.

Comment: There may be licensing, grant or resource issues related to the `SERVER01` library connection.

Comment: You likely have date limits that don't work. Check your logic that tells the code to execute or not, that work with the dates. Or at least post that section.